# Why does reflectivity suddenly change around critical angle?

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction

Why does reflectivity suddenly change around critical angle? 
For example, consider the situation when incident light travel in dielectrics A and go in to dielectric B. Assume the dielectric constant $\epsilon_A=2.25$ and $\epsilon_B=1.25$. Total internal reflection occur when incident angle is around 46,7 degree. I'm wondering why reflectivity arise so sharply and suddenly? The reflectiviy is almost 0 when incident angle < 30 degree. And suddenly arise around critical angle. This is weird.

P.S
Sorry. I only focus on TM wave unconsciously.

Comment: Beyond the critical angle, refraction out of the medium is impossible.

Comment: Because the equations require it.

Comment: It doesn't. To first order in the difference between the incidence angle $\theta_i$ and the critical angle $\theta_c$, the reflectivity increases linearly, $R \approx k |\theta_i-\theta_c|$ for some constant $k$.

Answer (score 1):

you can see the Fresnel coefficients for reflectivity and phase-change behavior below for dense to light-medium propagation that cause TIR (total internal reflection):
TE polarization:
[image]
TM polarization:
[image]

As a mathematical answer, near critical angle phase matching forces boundary to have to mirror-like behavior so reflection has to jumps to 1.

Comment: Thank you for answering. What is theta B in the phase changing graph of TM wave?

Comment: it's Brewster angle. in this angle, TM mode gets removed from reflection.